# Android studio - get city from GPS location errors

Tags: android, gps

I'm trying to learn some basic programming with android studio but so far I'm stuck because I'm not able to make work even code examples I've found on the internet. I'm trying to get current GPS location and then use it to get name of the city. In the first part (see buttonabc and related onclicklistener) I tried to get just the GPS location. It seemed to work at the begining but after I made some changes to the code it stoped working and now I can't make it work even if I copy back original code. I always get for latitude and longitude 0 and 0 values. I tried to send different GPS coordinates through Android device manager but nothing changed.
In the second part (see button named button and related onclicklistener) I've tried to make work different code that should return the name of the city. The result is that I don't even get toast to show any message at all. I have these permissions in android manifest: ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, INTERNET and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION.

I get also several errors during starting the application that I'm not exactly sure what they're suppossed to mean. Some examples:

```
03-30 12:20:38.100 2968-2981/? W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
03-30 12:20:38.100 2968-2981/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xabeeb340, error=EGL_SUCCESS
03-30 12:20:41.340 2968-2981/? E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xb4096600
03-30 12:21:04.941 1301-1317/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
03-30 12:21:04.951 1301-1317/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq
                                                       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                           at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                           at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                           at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                           at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49)
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002)
                                                           at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                           at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                           at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                        Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                           at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                           at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                           at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                           at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                           at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                           at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.KernelCpuSpeedReader.readDelta(KernelCpuSpeedReader.java:49) 
                                                           at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8002) 
                                                           at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                           at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                           at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                           at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
03-30 12:21:04.952 1301-1317/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime
                                                         java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
                                                             at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71)
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031)
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366)
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125)
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                             at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
                                                          Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
                                                             at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
                                                             at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186)
                                                             at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438)
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:76) 
                                                             at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103) 
                                                             at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.KernelUidCpuTimeReader.readDelta(KernelUidCpuTimeReader.java:71) 
                                                             at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.updateCpuTimeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:8031) 
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService.updateExternalStats(BatteryStatsService.java:1366) 
                                                             at com.android.server.am.BatteryStatsService$BatteryStatsHandler.handleMessage(BatteryStatsService.java:125) 
                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                             at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61) 
                                                             at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46) 
01-01 00:00:00.000 0-0/? E/Internal: device 'emulator-5554' not found
```

I tried to google some of these errors but solution like "uncheck use host GPU option" just led to not being able to run project at all.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Button btnShowLocation;

    GPSTracker gps;
    String test = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonabc);

        btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

                if (gps.canGetLocation()) {
                    double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Your Location is aaa -\nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: "
                                    + longitude + pokus, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    gps.showSettingsAlert();
                }
            }
        });

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), true);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location locations = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        List<String>  providerList = locationManager.getAllProviders();
        if(null!=locations && null!=providerList && providerList.size()>0){
            double longitude = locations.getLongitude();
            double latitude = locations.getLatitude();
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                List<Address> listAddresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                if(null!=listAddresses&&listAddresses.size()>0){
                    pokus = listAddresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "bbb" + test, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        }
    }
}





import android.Manifest;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    private final Context context;

    boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
    boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
    boolean canGetLocation = false;

    Location location;

    double latitude;
    double longitude;

    private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10;
    private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1;

    protected LocationManager locationManager;

    public GPSTracker(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        getLocation();
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        try {
            locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

            isGPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

            isNetworkEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {

            } else {
                this.canGetLocation = true;

                if (isNetworkEnabled) {

                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        return null;
                    }
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

                        if (location != null) {

                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }

                }

                if (isGPSEnabled) {
                    if (location == null) {
                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                                MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                                MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);

                        if (locationManager != null) {
                            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

                            if (location != null) {
                                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return location;
    }


    public void stopUsingGPS() {
        if (locationManager != null) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
        }
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
        return latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        if(location != null) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }

        return longitude;
    }

    public boolean canGetLocation() {
        return this.canGetLocation;
    }

    public void showSettingsAlert() {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

        alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

}
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks in adance for any reply.

Answer (score 0):

This is not how you should get user location.
Try like [this](https://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/location/retrieve-current.html).